# Generate thumbnail from video using azure media service (video encoder) using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, video, azure-media-services

[How to generate thumbnails using Media Encoder Standard with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-generate-thumbnail-with-mes)

Above link shows preset for generating thumbnail from video in .NET, i am using same preset for generating single thumbnail image using node.js. I am trying to create a transform using `azureMediaServicesClient.transforms.createOrUpdate(resourceGroup, accountName, transformName, preset);` function of MediaServices from "azure-arm-mediaservices" [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-mediaservices) as described in 
[media-services-v3-node-tutorials](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/master/AMSv3Samples).

Currently i am getting an error when trying to create transform for thumbnail generation however it works fine for video encoding using "**BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset**".

Does anyone know hoe to generate thumbnail form video using Node.js? Any help on this is highly appreciated!
Regards.

Comment: I also tried to create transform to generate thumbnails using azure CLI command but it also failed. Is there anything i am missing or the preset is no more valid ?

Comment: Hi, I think my answer can be used as a solution to your problem. You can give it a try. I think that by shortening the interval, you should only get one thumbnail.

Comment: In addition, I recommend that you can try using third-party media-thumbnail if the `# Microsoft.Media.JpgImage` solution does not work.

Comment: I wonder if your problem is solved? Does my answer help you? If there is a better way to solve this problem, you can also send your own answers, which can better help others in the forum.

Comment: I was unable to solve the problem, i think there was a problem with preset.